# Changes not applied on AVD?

Tags: android, eclipse, emulation, android-virtual-device, cocos2d-android

i am new to cocos2d-x i am making app for Android using cocos2d-x
in Android emulator their is no changes applied in it!
I mean i change HelloWorld.png to game.png and Hello World to Game but nothing works in emulator it is showing Hello World and HelloWorld.png
game.png is in assets

I clean my Project close eclipse emulator but problem is still there!!!
I uninstall APK from emulator but no LUCK!

console message:
bash /build_native.sh NDK_DEBUG=1 V=1 all 
/usr/bin/bash: /build_native.sh: No such file or directory

Please help! me 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you missing the . in front of the script when inside your build folder?

ie:

```
bash ./build_native.sh NDK_DEBUG=1 V=1 all
```

Comment: THANKS! for replying to my Question i add this in c/c++ Build:    bash ${workspace_loc:/work} ./build_native.sh NDK_DEBUG=1 V=1 all now emulator is not even running Unfortunately, work has stopped. CONSOLE MESSAGE: 01:30:40 **** Incremental Build of configuration Default for project work **** bash "C:\\Projects\\cocos2d-x\\work\\proj.android" ./build_native.sh NDK_DEBUG=1 V=1 all all C:\Projects\cocos2d-x\work\proj.android: C:\Projects\cocos2d-x\work\proj.android: is a directory I hope you HELP me!

Comment: Are you using cygwin or something on Windows? I'm just curious about the Windows file system paths in there. It's also hard to tell which parts of your comment are command and output. Could you update your question using the code formatting and a little more detail?

Comment: i solve Problem! i missed to click build all in eclipse anyway THANK YOU!!! for replying to messages. :)